# IntelliJ support for Definitely Typed Stubs for UnderscoreJS

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, definitelytyped

I have downloaded `underscore` and `async` Definitely typed library for my project in IntelliJ and both of them are enabled with Node.JS Core support available too.

[image: IntelliJ Preferences Screen]

I am able to get suggestions and resolved colors for async methods, but not for underscoreJs methods.

[image: async and underscore methods in different color] [image: underscoreJS method as unresolved in IntelliJ]

IntelliJ Idea version 2017.1.2

UnderscoreJs version 1.8.3

So my question is 
**How can I add support for underscoreJS too?**

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

[image]

Please `Ctrl+click` on `_` - what definition are you taken to?

[image]

Comment: It takes me to this line in my file `var _ = require("underscore");`

Comment: what underscore and Idea versions do you use? With Idea 2017.1.2 + underscore 1.8.3, I don't even need to install typescript stubs - underscore methods are correctly resolved from `/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js`

Comment: Did you add `node_modules` in 'Libraries' of 'Javascript' in 'Project Preferences'? Can you please send a screenshot of the same place similar to 1st image in my question?

Comment: WebStorm did it for me - it includes all direct dependencies listed in package.json as javascript libraries. I've attached screenshot - see the updated answer